# I want to get accessToken from google oauth without opening browser or without opening any google popup using node js

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client, google-photos-api

I don't want to open any google form or modal from authentication.
Is there any way to authenticate and get all the google photos using clientId and clientSecret using node js as server only.

I tried some samples given over github and followed some more google stufs.

- https://github.com/googleworkspace/node-samples

Comment: Why is it necessary to use clientSecret authentication, why you cannot use for example API key?

Comment: had the same issue. Check my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74652665/google-auth-service-account-bearer-photo-api