# Google Auth Service Account Bearer Photo API

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, service-accounts, google-photos, google-photos-api

I am trying to upload an image to google photos service using a google service account with a domain-wide delegation to use a *user@domain.com* account.

Somehow I only get a 401 error: "Authentication session is not defined." using the code below

What am I doing wrong?

CODE:

```
class GooglePhotosApi:
    def __init__(self):
        self.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = (
            os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/service_account.json"
        )
        self.SCOPES = [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.sharing",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.appendonly",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
        ]



def auth_service_account(self):
        self.credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            self.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,
            scopes=self.SCOPES,
            subject="*user@domain.com*",
        )

        self.access_token = self.credentials._make_authorization_grant_assertion()
        return self.credentials


def upload_media(self, img):
    self.service = discovery.build(
        "photoslibrary", "v1", credentials=self.credentials, static_discovery=False
    )

    # step 1: Upload byte data to Google Server
    image_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/"
    upload_url = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads"

    headers = {
        # "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(self.access_token.decode("utf-8")),
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + str(self.access_token),
        "Content-type": "application/octet-stream",
        "X-Goog-Upload-Protocol": "raw",
    }

    image_file = os.path.join(image_dir, "img.jpg")
    headers["X-Goog-Upload-File-Name"] = "img.jpg"

    img = open(image_file, "rb").read()
    response = requests.post(upload_url, data=img, headers=headers)

    request_body = {
        "newMediaItems": [
            {
                "description": "Static Name",
                "simpleMediaItem": {
                    "uploadToken": response.content.decode("utf-8")
                },
            }
        ]
    }

    upload_response = (
        self.service.mediaItems().batchCreate(body=request_body).execute()
    )

    return upload_response
```

These are the domains for the domain-wide delegation:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar,
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary,
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.sharing,
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.appendonly,
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam

Thank you!

SOLUTION:

OK I figured out how to obtain the correct JWT token. I simply needed to access the newly created discovery build after I send a request with the API based function and then extract the JWT token afterwards. This way I am using the JWT token from the API call in my request.post call. Here is the code:

```
def upload_media(self, img):

    self.service = discovery.build(
        "photoslibrary", "v1", credentials=self.credentials, static_discovery=False
    )
    results = (
        self.service.albums()
        .list(pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken,albums(id,title)")
        .execute()
    )

    # step 1: Upload byte data to Google Server
    image_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/"
    upload_url = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads"

    headers = {
        # "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(self.access_token.decode("utf-8")),
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + str(self.service._http.credentials.token),
        "Content-type": "application/octet-stream",
        "X-Goog-Upload-Protocol": "raw",
    }

    image_file = os.path.join(image_dir, "img.jpg")
    headers["X-Goog-Upload-File-Name"] = "img.jpg"

    img = open(image_file, "rb").read()
    response = requests.post(upload_url, data=img, headers=headers)

    # upload_response = self.service.uploads().(body=request_body).execute()
    request_body = {
        "newMediaItems": [
            {
                "description": "Kuma the corgi",
                "simpleMediaItem": {
                    "uploadToken": response.content.decode("utf-8")
                },
            }
        ]
    }

    upload_response = (
        self.service.mediaItems().batchCreate(body=request_body).execute()
    )

    return upload_response
```

Thank you and happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consult the Google Photos api documentation on [service-accounts](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/authorization#service-accounts)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I can tell from the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth 
One could generate a domain-wide JWT token for a service account that acts as a user.